# What is this script that's injected in every webpage I visit, and if malicious how to get rid of it?

Tags: google-chrome, security, browser, javascript, xss

I found this script when inspecting webpages and I have no idea where this is coming from or if this is malicious. Is this malicious, how can I find out where it came from and how to get rid of that?

```
var tvt = tvt || {}; tvt.captureVariables = function(a){for(var b=
new Date,c={},d=Object.keys(a||{}),e=0,f;f=d[e];e++)if(a.hasOwnProperty(f)&&"undefined"!=typeof a[f])try{var g=[];c[f]=JSON.stringify(a[f],function(h,k){try{if("function"!==typeof k){if("object"===typeof k&&null!==k){if(k instanceof HTMLElement||k instanceof Node||-1!=g.indexOf(k))return;g.push(k)}return k}}catch(m){}})}catch(h){}a=document.createEvent("CustomEvent");a.initCustomEvent("TvtRetrievedVariablesEvent",!0,!0,{variables:c,date:b});window.dispatchEvent(a)};window.setTimeout(function() {tvt.captureVariables({'dataLayer.hide': (function(a){a=a.split(".");for(var b=window,c=0;c<a.length&&(b=b[a[c]],b);c++);return b})('dataLayer.hide'),'gaData': window['gaData'],'dataLayer': window['dataLayer']})}, 2000);
```

Comment: Answered here: [javascript - What is this script on most of the pages I navigate to? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686105/what-is-this-script-on-most-of-the-pages-i-navigate-to)